# JFrog Artifactory as build parameter in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jfrog-cli

Have a jfrog artifactory setup with Generic Package type
Able to upload artifacts to jfrog from a build job, no issues there.
Using Extensible/extended choice parameter plugin, would want to provide the build details as parameters to jenkins builds, having a hard time to get it up and running. All links or plugins refer to Nexus, none to jfrog.
Any clues will be of immense help

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you're looking for? Is it your question how to specify parameters while uploading an artifact to JFrog Artifactory?

Comment: i would want to provide an available jfrog artifact as a parameter in jenkins job

Comment: In that case you could create a parameterized build in Jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) where one of the parameters is the location of the artifact in Artifactory: http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?LOCATION=generic-local%2FmyArtifact.zip for example.